# Curious: Why is the "throws <SomeSpecific>Exception" syntax required in Java alone?

Tags: java

We all know it is needed.

But WHY is it needed in Java alone, when other similar languages that have exception handling capablities don't require us to write "throws Exception"? Is there anyone who knows what was happening when Java language was designed and why they made it that way? Just curious.

P.S. This may not be a practical or really necessary question - it might not help me in anyway with my ongoing projects. But certain language features kindle my curiosity :D

**Edit**
Looks like my question was very vague! I think I worded the question wrongly. We need to use the "throws Exception" kind of syntax at some points during programming when dealing with Java code. But something like that is never needed in C# or C++ or even VB.Net and PHP. So why Java alone insists on this?

Comment: It was my understanding that you only added `throws exception` when the calling method is REQUIRED to handle those exceptions. Maybe I'm wrong though, I very well could be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other answers here have pointed out, the `throws` clause is only required for **[checked exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions)**, which is a feature that currently only exists in Java.

The official answer as to **why** Java has checked exceptions is [well documented](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> Why did the designers decide to force
>   a method to specify all uncaught
>   checked exceptions that can be thrown
>   within its scope? Any Exception that
>   can be thrown by a method is part of
>   the method's public programming
>   interface. Those who call a method
>   must know about the exceptions that a
>   method can throw so that they can
>   decide what to do about them. These
>   exceptions are as much a part of that
>   method's programming interface as its
>   parameters and return value.

However, this decision is [highly controversial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254.html), even within the Java community:

> Recently, several well-regarded
>   experts, including Bruce Eckel and Rod
>   Johnson, have publicly stated that
>   while they initially agreed completely
>   with the orthodox position on checked
>   exceptions, they've concluded that
>   exclusive use of checked exceptions is
>   not as good an idea as it appeared at
>   first, and that checked exceptions
>   have become a significant source of
>   problems for many large projects.
>   Eckel takes a more extreme view,
>   suggesting that all exceptions should
>   be unchecked; Johnson's view is more
>   conservative, but still suggests that
>   the orthodox preference for checked
>   exceptions is excessive. (It's worth
>   noting that the architects of C#, who
>   almost certainly had plenty of
>   experience using Java technology,
>   chose to omit checked exceptions from
>   the language design, making all
>   exceptions unchecked exceptions. They
>   did, however, leave room for an
>   implementation of checked exceptions
>   at a later time.)

Personally, I find checked exceptions to be useful **only** when your API makes a habit of catching all exceptions and re-throwing them as something appropriate to your abstraction layer.  For example, an in-memory object cache that happens to use a disk or SQL backend to cache data should never throw `IOException` or `SQLException` -- instead, it should throw (and declare) some user-defined exception like `CacheFailureException` or similar.

Also, you might find Ned Batchelder's article [Exceptions in the Rainforest](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-in-the-rainforest.html) illuminating in regard to this question.

Answer (score 3):

It declares that the method can raise an exception, and allows developers and their tools to ensure that they have considered that possibility.

However, the question is imprecise. The declaration is only required when the exception is a "checked" exception. And then, a more specific type of exception should be declared. Throwing a `java.lang.Exception` is poor style.

Runtime exceptions, that is, exceptions raised by the runtime when specific bugs are encountered, are not *required* to be declared. Runtime exceptions should be thrown when the error can be prevented by better programming, and doesn't depend on environmental conditions at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not require you to write `throws Exception` on a function declaration, so it is not "needed" in general. It requires you to declare the exceptions that may be thrown by the function, which might be no exceptions at all, or just runtime exceptions. Indeed, using `throws Exception` is probably a sign of lazy coding, as it acts as an uninformative catch-all.

*edit* — well now that you've edited your question, the answer you're looking for (as others have said) is that Java has the concept of "checked" exceptions. It was simply a design decision, to supposedly improve code quality. It probably doesn't really help much in the long run; you can't fix a bad coder with a language trick.

Comment: I don't think the poster meant the exact code `throws Exception` in that sense. I guess he wanted to know why java wants the programmer to declare exceptions that are thrown from the method like that and the Exception is a placeholder for other Exceptions like FileNotFoundException etc.

Comment: @Faisal Exactly... I am editing my question as and when confusions arise. Looks like its actually pretty vague!

Comment: Oh, well if he didn't mean that, perhaps he shouldn't have typed it in exactly like that :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of exceptions

1. Checked Exceptions
2. UnChecked Exceptions

The throws clause tells which checked Exceptions are thrown by the method so that the caller can handle these in the code or they would have to add the throws clause so that in the end someone will have to handle these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a very organized language which prevents in many situations the unexperient user from missing something relevant or of importance, at least so that errors can be displayed later with a good hint or explanation for what is missing. Forcing you to mention the exceptions on a function/method declaration is a way to keep with that politics and at the same time a way to allow you to define your own specific exceptions and putting them to use.

Answer (score 1):

The point of declaring exceptions in Java was to force the programmer to handle the errors that can arise when executing the program. However, experience showed that in a lot of cases, programmers' "handling" of exceptions did not really handle the exceptions but instead ignored them:

```
void writeToFile() {
  try {
      ...
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      // Nothing here
  }
}
```

So in languages more recent than Java the designers preferred not to check exceptions, so that programs without error checking would at least crash with a meaningful stack trace, so you would have a bug easy to debug instead of your program "misteriously" malfunctioning.

Personally I like checked exceptions in Java because:

- I do not mishandle exceptions.
- Exceptions make me be aware of possible problems that my code could have.
- Code is better documented that way.

but I can understand unchecked exceptions. Most of the time I handle an exception is to log it, wrap it with some subclass of `RuntimeException` and rethrow, because they could only be caused by bugs / misconfiguration / broken deployment. I like to use checked exceptions only for business rule violations.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood the rationale as put forward by the Java designers, the error situations are generally put in two categories:

- Those that are non-fatal and the calling code with good reason should be able to recover from.  FileNotFoundException when reading form files, and IOExceptions when working with sockets.
- Those that are fatal if they cannot with good reason be expected by the calling code.  This includes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and ArithmeticException (when dividing by zero).